# Chrome92でerr_connection_resetと表示される

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome92、Android System Webview92、Chromeアプリ92にて、err_connection_resetが表示され、アクセス不可の状態になっています。
FirefoxやSafariではアクセスできています。
同サーバーの別サイトは問題なくアクセスできる状態で、原因が不明です。

Answer (score -1):

this err_connection_reset is happening on Colombia with only one ISP, the issue is on TCP layer, but I can't found any place to report it to chrome.